# Reverse engineer "compiled" Perl vs. C?

Tags: c, perl, reverse-engineering, code-access-security

Have a client that's claiming complied C is harder to reverse engineer than sudo "compiled" Perl byte-code, or the like. Anyone have a way to prove, or disprove this?

Comment: Which compiler are you using to compile your perl code? If its compiling to machine code then there should be no difference, however if its byte-code then it may be easier.

Comment: Harder based on what? I'm sure more people are more familiar with reversing ASM of a popular architecture than with Perl bytecode, but that doesn't imply that it's inherently more difficult.

Comment: +1 @Cody: If it's possible to easily compile Perl to machine code, then yes. If no, but byte-code is easy then byte code.

Comment: +1 @yan: Harder based level of skill, cost of methods used, and time to execute, etc

Comment: I think that reversing c is much harder that reversing perl in theory. But it's very well possible that the available reversing tools for perl are much less developed making it harder in practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know too much about perl, but I'll give some examples why reversing code compiled to assembly is so ugly.

The ugliest thing about reverse engineering c code is that the compilation removes all type information.  This total lack of names and types is very the worst part IMO.
In a dynamically typed language the compiler needs to preserve much more information about that. In particular the names of fields/methods/... since these are usually strings for which it is impossible to find every use.

There is plenty of other ugly stuff. Such as whole program optimization using different registers to pass parameters every time. Functions being inlined so what was one a simple function appears in many places, often in slightly different form due to optimizations.

The same registers and bytes on the stack get reused by different content inside a function. Gets especially ugly with arrays on the stack. Since you have no way to know how big the array is and where it ends.

Then there are micro-optimizations which can get annoying. For example I once spend >15 minutes to reverse a simple function that once was similar to `return x/1600`. Because the compiler decided that divisions are slow and rewrote that division by a constant into several multiplications additions and bitwise-operations.

Comment: . did you have this: http://www.hex-rays.com/decompiler.shtml ? Would probably have taken 1 second to get to x/1600; this has its querks but is so good in RE scenarios that it is well worth the hefty price tags if you do RE as a day job.

Comment: @Pra No, that's quite a bit above my budget. And while it might deal with some issues (like the x/1600 example) the loss of type information is hard to reverse. From somebody who used that decompiler a few years ago I heard that the results weren't that impressive, but it might have gotten better since then(the decompiler was pretty new back then)

Answer (score 2):

Perl is really easy to [reverse engineer](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq3.html#How_can_I_hide_the_s).  The tool of choice is vi, vim, emacs or notepad.

Comment: Yes, now that perlcc is out of the main distribution and no longer an option for some.

Answer (score 2):

That does raise the question about why they're worried about reverse engineering.  It is more difficult to turn machine code back to something resembling the original source code than it is byte-code normally but for most nefarious activities that's irrelevant.  If someone wants to copy your secrets or break your security they can do enough without turning it back into a perfect representation of your original source code.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse engineering code for a virtual machine is *usually* easier. A virtual machine is typically designed to be an easy target for the language. That means it typically represents the constructs of that language reasonably easily and directly.

If, however, you're dealing with a VM that wasn't designed for that particular language (e.g., Perl compiled to the JVM) that would frequently put you back much closer to working with code generated for real hardware -- i.e., you have to do whatever's necessary to target a pre-defined architecture instead of designing the target to fit the source.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there has been suficient debate on this over the years; and mostly the results are never conclusive ... mainly because it doesn't matter.

For a motivated reverse engineer, both will be the same.

If you are using pseudo exe makers like perl2exe then that will be easier to "decompile" than compiled C, as perl2exe does not compile the perl at all, it's just a bit "hidden" (see http://www.net-security.org/vuln.php?id=2464 ; this is really old, but concept is probably still the same (I haven't researched so don't know for sure, but I hope you get my point) )

I would advise look at the language which is best for the job so maintenance and development of the actual product can be done sensibly and sustainably.

Remember you _can_not_ stop a motivated adversary, you need to make it more expensive to reverse than to write it themselves.

These 4 should make it difficult (but again not impossible)...

[1] Insert noise code (random places, random code) which does pointless maths and complex data structure interaction (if done properly this will be a great headache if the purpose is to reverse the code rather than the functionality).

[2] Chain a few (different) code obfuscators on the source code as part of build process.

[3] Apply a Software protection dongle which will prevent code execution if the h/w is not present, this will mean physical access to the dongle's data is required before rest of the reversing can take place : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_protection_dongle

[4] There are always protectors (e.g. Themida http://www.oreans.com/themida.php) you can get which will be able to protect a .exe after it has been built (regardless of how it was compiled).

... That should give the reverser enough headache.

But remember that all this will also cost money, so you should always weigh up what is it that you are trying to achieve and then look at your options.

In short: Both methods are equally insecure. Unless you are using a non-compiling perl-to-exe maker in which case native compiled EXE wins.

I hope this helps.

Comment: btw, [1] and [2] should be done as build process and not as development process so you never affect your source tree with this noise or you won't be able to hire anyone to maintain your code :P

Comment: +1 @PrashantGupta: For this alone... "you need to make it more expensive to reverse than to write it themselves" -- beyond that, all the additionally links and suggestions are a huge help, thanks!!

Comment: +2 @PrashantGupta: "or you won't be able to hire anyone to maintain your code"... made me laugh, just thinking about editing %@*$ code is sort of funny. And yeah, I agree Perl B::C (www.perl-compiler.org) does look interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

C is harder to decompile than byte-compiled Perl code. Any Perl code that's been byte-compiled can be decompiled. Byte-compiled code is not machine code like in compiled C programs. Some others suggested using code obfuscation techniques. Those are just tricks to make code harder to read and won't effect the difficulty in decompiling the Perl source. The decompiled source may be harder to read but there are many Perl de-obfuscation tools available and even a Perl module:

[http://metacpan.org/pod/B::Deobfuscate](http://metacpan.org/pod/B%3a%3aDeobfuscate)

Perl packing programs like Par, PerlAPP or Perl2exe won't offer source code protection either. At some point the source has to be extracted so Perl can execute the script. Even packers like PerlAPP and Perl2exe, which attempt some encryption techniques on the source, can be defeated with a debugger:

http://www.perlmonks.org/?displaytype=print;node_id=779752;replies=1

It'll stop someone from casually browsing your Perl code but even the packer has to unpack the script before it can be run. Anyone who's determined can get the source code.

Decompiling C is a different beast altogether. Once it's compiled it's now machine code. You either end up with Assembly code with most C decompilers or some of the commercial C decompilers will take the Assembly code and try to generate equivalent C code but, unless it's a really simple program, seldom are able to recreate the original code.